# geom_area with fill colour based on value

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, geom-area

I'd like to make a `geom_area` plot with the fill colour based on the `y` (or any other) value, similar to the `geom_density_ridges_gradient` function of the `ggridges` package. I could achieve this with multiple `geom_col`s but I want to have the nice smooth `geom_area` style. Do you have any idea?

This code illustrates what I want to do:

```
data <- data.frame(x = 1:100,
                   y = rnorm(100, 20,3))


#I'd like to have an area plot with the fill colour based on the y values
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_area(aes(fill = y))

#As in a bar plot, but with a smooth area, not a composite of rectangles
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_col(aes(fill = y))
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you want to provide the _contour_ of the `geom_area` but with the left-to-right color changes of `geom_col` (without the inter-bar spacing), is that right? Isn't that more of a left-to-right gradient?

Comment: Said differently, what about the `geom_col` plot needs to be changed: space between columns; change from boxy-tops to a peak-to-peak line; anything else?

Comment: @r2evans
Yes, I'd like to have the `geom_col` plot with the contour of the `geom_area`, i.e. a "smooth" contour and not rectangles. And yes, also no gaps between the bars, so I'd set `width = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `approx` to get a huge number of interpolated values and plot them as very thin vertical `geom_segment`s

```r
data2 <- as.data.frame(approx(data$x, data$y, seq(1, 100, len = 5000)))

ggplot(data = data2, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x, yend = 0, colour = y), linewidth = 0.1) +
  geom_area(fill = NA, color = "black") +
  scale_color_viridis_c() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]